# Django Url does not work

Tags: django, django-templates, django-views, django-urls

I am trying to obtain a url to a view that renders an image so I can use it in an img tag with href. 
But my `{% url viewname object_id %}` is not working. Here are the specifics:

my urls.py:

```
hydrourlpatterns = patterns('',

    url(r'^graphs/$','hydro.views.graphs',name='graphs'),
    url(r'^graphs/new/$', 'hydro.views.add_graph', name='add_graph'),
    url(r'^graphs/(?P<graph_id>\d+?)/$', 'hydro.views.single_graph', name='graph_detail'),
    url(r'^graphs/graphImage/(?P<graph_id>\d+?)/$', 'hydro.views.render_graph', name='graphImage')



)
```

my template(url: localhost/graphs/(graph_id)/):

```
{% extends "subpage.django" %}
{% block content %}

{% if graph %}
    <h3> {{ graph.name }} </h3>
    <h1> {% url 'graphImage' graph_id %} </h1>
{% endif %}


{% endblock  %}
```

The error I keep getting is ViewDoesNotExsist.

```
Could not import hydro.views.add_site. 
View does not exist in module hydro.views.
```

Comment: when I go to the link or hardcode the url it works. so i dont think its my views unless my arguments dont match up

Comment: I've tried just printing out the url to by <p> {% url 'someviewname' %}</p> but it doesn't work. Do you know how to display out a url variable for testing purposes? That would help alot

Comment: What is `add_site` ? Is it a py file, or a method ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You use `hydro.views.add_site` somewhere else in your `urls.py`.  Comment this url line or create `add_site` view in the `hydro.views`.

**EDIT**: You don't pass `graph_id` variable to the template so change `{% url %}` call to:

```
{% url 'graphImage' graph.id %}
```

Comment: I have an add_site view, I don't know why thats coming up I have the proper syntax and that's like a bunch of urls up from it.

Comment: Show the `add_site` code and whole `urls.py`, please.

Comment: can't show add_site due to work sensitivity. But did some other stuff and now we have this error:  NoRevereMatch  Reverse for 'graphImage' with arguments '('',)' and keyword arguments '{}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['graphs/graphImage/(?P<graph_id>\\d+?)/$']

Comment: I am assuming its my url path for graphImage. Still don't know how to fix though

Comment: Sweet thanks, I keep getting confused cause sometimes it wants graph_id or graph.id. It works!